Why do we say Tzidkatcha Tzedek almost every Shabbat Mincha
It is known that in the Shabbat Mincha we use to say Tzidekatcha Tzedek for accepting the decree for the death of Moshe Rabbino who passed away during these hours as can be seen here. However, he died on the 7th of Adar, why is it then we say Tzidekatcha Tzedek almost every Shabbat and not just near the day of his death?

Great question! Could be improved by replacing "it is known" with "it says [here]" - i.e. show your sources :)

It's not just Moshe. It's also Yosef and David. So already that would be 3 Shabbosim on which to say it.

The rishonim brought in the tur in orach chaim 292 bring that moshe died on shabbos at the time of mincha. Do you mean to ask why we by moshe mourn the day of the week as opposed to the day of the year as we usually do?

Yes @אילפא, this is my question. You usually mourn only on Yortzehyt and not every week along the year. Moreover, you don't mourn in Shabbat but in Yom Chol.
